# how do I cast a string column to a number of higher precision in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am using hibernate 5.1.0 with the dialect MySQL5Dialect.

In my code, I have a point where as part of a criteria builder I cast an expression to decimal number. But the default precision is too low or the produce SQL is not MySQL compatible.

Here are the results of my trial
[image]

The first two are not valid for MySQL and the rest reduce the precision so the query does not do the intended filtering. 
I need to have the cast with higher precision but I am not able to do so. I also tried using function but the call to createQuery gets stuck.

```
builder.function("CAST", Double.class, valueExpression, builder.literal("decimal(30,30)"))
```

valueExpression is of type javax.Path